# So what can I replace TTTableTextItem with?

Tags: iphone, ios, three20

So here's what I'm working with.
I'm trying to get rid of the Three20 framework...but I'm not sure what I should replace this specifically with:

```
NSMutableArray *selectedPeople = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSArray *cells = [textField cells];

for (TTTableTextItem *cell in cells) {
    NSDictionary *person = [textField.dataSource contactInfoAtIndex:[cell.URL integerValue]];
    [selectedPeople addObject:person];
    [AppPreferences incrementContactUsage:[[person objectForKey:@"abId"] intValue]];
}
```

I've got a textfield that is implemented similar to the Token field view in the Messages app. (using JSTokenField... I've replaced TTPickerView with that).

I'm fairly new to the iOS scene, and I'm working on an old project (trying to get it out of the gutter).

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: +1 for trying to get rid of Three20.

Comment: Thank you, its an absolute mess!